# Why the mle function can not run with lower and upper bound?

Tags: r, statistics, distribution, mle

I tried to use mle to estimate the parameters for the negative binomial distribution. Here is my code.

```
library(stats4)
library(bbmle)
library(MASS)

b=rnbinom(n=1000, size=3, prob=0.1)

LL2 <- function(size, prob) {
  R = dnbinom(b, size, prob, log = TRUE)
  -sum(R)
}
```

When I set the mle function with lower and upper bound, I got

```
stats4::mle(LL2, start = list(size = 3, prob = 0.1),lower = c(-Inf,-Inf),upper = c(Inf,Inf))
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, lower = lower,  : 
  L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
```

When I removed the bounds

```
stats4::mle(LL2, start = list(size = 3, prob = 0.1))

Call:
stats4::mle(minuslogl = LL2, start = list(size = 3, prob = 0.1))

Coefficients:
     size      prob 
3.0467857 0.1037522
```

However, if I change the bounds to a finite value, the error is still there.

I was wondering why this happened? Is that because the L-BFGS-B method can not handle with bounds settings?

Any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the point of setting bounds to be `-Inf` to `Inf` - that's the same as unbounded.

Comment: what finite values did you try?

Answer (score 2):

I ran your setup code with `set.seed(101)`.

Create an instrumented version of the score function so we can see where the optimizer is going:

```r
LL2 <- function(size, prob) {
   R = dnbinom(b, size, prob, log = TRUE)
   res <- -sum(R)
   cat(size,prob,res,"\n")
   res
}
stats4::mle(LL2, start = list(size = 3, prob = 0.1),lower = c(-Inf,-Inf),upper = c(Inf,Inf))
## 3 0.1 4085.146 
## 3.001 0.1 4085.166 
## 2.999 0.1 4085.127 
## 3 0.101 4084.767 
## 3 0.099 4085.858 
## 2.964666 1.099376 NaN
```

> Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, lower = lower,  :
> L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'
> In addition: Warning message:
> In dnbinom(b, size, prob, log = TRUE) : NaNs produced

The first 5 steps are the evaluation of initial value and of the finite difference approximation of the derivatives.  The very next optimization step takes us to `prob = 1.099`, which gives us an `NaN` result (we need 0 < prob < 1).  L-BFGS-B is much more finicky than the other optimizers about non-finite values; most of the others treat non-finite results as "bad" and try something sensible.

You could set the lower bound to 0 for `size` and bounds (0,1) for `prob` ... (I tried it and it seems to work).  You do have to be a little bit careful with L-BFGS-B - it doesn't always respect the bounds when it is calculating the finite-difference approximation, so e.g. if values <= 0 will give non-finite results you may need to set the lower bound slightly *above* 0 (e.g. 0.002, since the default finite-difference epsilon is 0.001).